# Using Highcharts in ExtJS 4.2.2

Tags: extjs, svg, highcharts

I try to use Highcharts i ExtJS.
I wrote my app.js:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
            Ext.define('myModel', {
                extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                fields: [{ name: 'month' }, { name: 'value' }]
            });

            Ext.define('myStore', {
                extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
                model: 'myModel',
                data: [{
                    month: '1',
                    value: 1
                }, {
                    month: '2',
                    value: 12
                }]
            });

            var sto = Ext.create('myStore');

            var win = new Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                layout: 'fit',
                width: 480,
                height: 320,
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'highchart',
                    series: [{
                        dashStyle: 'DashDot',
                        dataIndex: 'value'
                    }],
                    xField: 'month',
                    store: sto,
                    chartConfig: {
                        chart: {
                            type: 'spline'
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'A simple graph'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }).show();
        });
```

The page loaded without errors, but there is no any chart on the form.
I checked, some elements were added in DOM, but I can't see it on the form.
Importantly, that the elements, which were added don't contain the SVG components, they are only DIVs (empty DIVs) with id like: 'highchart-1010-north-handle'.

It is my first highchart sample in ExtJS.
I use [this](http://joekuan.org/demos/Highcharts_Sencha/docs/#!/api/Chart.ux.Highcharts) as an example, but result was equal - no errors, but no any charts on the form too.

Did I do something wrong?

I shared [full example](https://github.com/mmameko/test/blob/master/index.html).

Comment: Does somebody can show me working example using Highchart in ExtJS?

Comment: First of all, remove `new` operator from Ext.create call and try again.

Comment: I remove new operator from Ext.create - there is no result

Comment: I shared full example in: https://github.com/mmameko/test/blob/master/index.html